# jquery datepicker returns undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i m using datepicker to get the date. I had done the jquery datepicker but **its returns undefined value**. please help me.

HTML CODE

```
<input type="text" class="form-control fromdate" id="datepicker" name="from_date" placeholder="From date" value="<?php echo set_value('from_date'); ?>" >
```

script

```
var fromdate =  $('.fromdate').datepicker('getDate');
alert(fromdate);
```

Comment: When are you calling your script? On change? Click? Not on load I hope!!! Please show more of the page HTML/script.

Comment: i used Onchange event

Comment: Have you tried `$('.fromdate').val()`?

Comment: i used but it returns null

Comment: Please show the output HTML of the page (as saved from your browser). That will make identifying the problem easier. You may simply be missing jQueryUI etc.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: Turns out you get `null` if you do not initialise datepicker before calling a method on patepicker. Makes sense now (if he meant `null` and not `undefined` that is). :)

Comment: Yeah it does help to initialise a plugin first :)

Comment: It is standard SO etiquette to select one of the *earliest* correct answers. @huggilou correctly identified the problem first (about a minute before me and nearly an hour before Selva kumar's answer). Given the amount of code you displayed, and the uneeded complexity of the chosen answer, there is no way it is the most appropriate answer for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using datepicker we need to initalize it first

```
<input type="text" class="form-control fromdate" id="datepicker" name="from_date" value="2015-4-10"   />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fromdate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
    inline: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
            day  = date.getDate(),  
            month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
            year =  date.getFullYear();
        alert(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
    }
});

var fromdate =  $('.fromdate').datepicker('getDate');
alert(fromdate);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a jQuery UI widget, you first have to instantiate the widget before calling any functions on it:

```
$(function() {
    //Instanciate the widget
    $( ".fromdate" ).datepicker();
    //Access to widget's functions
    alert($( ".fromdate" ).datepicker('getDate'))
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mq8hmxdj/)

Note: `$(function(){ YOUR CODE HERE });` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){ YOUR CODE HERE });`

Comment: For getting to the heart of the problem, an hour before the "selected" answer +1 to you :)

Comment: No problem. We both answered correctly a very long time before the accepted answer arrived (which *does* work too, but has far more code than needed to illustrate the actual issue).

Answer (score 0):

Without your full page/code this is guesswork, but using `datepicker` is pretty simple. You need to "turn it on first", then use it:

```
$('.fromdate').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        var fromdate = $('.fromdate').datepicker('getDate');
        alert(fromdate);
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zr9ewogp/1/

You example seemed odd as the `onSelect` event passes the date value, so fetching it is not actually needed:

e.g.

```
$('.fromdate').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        alert(dateText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. How to set QueryString in jQuery:

```
var type="DataType";
window.location.href = `../../DashBoard/Index?Type=${type}`;
```

2. How to get QueryString in jQuery:

```
const queryString = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const type = queryString.get('Type');
```

Comment: Hey, if you want me to respond to your inquiries. Post it in a different thread.